# Unable to change JQuery Datepicker properties

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

The application that I'm working on has a common datepicker format setup. All pages inherit the following javascript in the header:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(':input[data-datepicker]').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyyy' });
});
```

Now I have a page where I need to add my own properties to the Datepicker such as get the MaxDate property setup:

```
Reference:
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.min.js")" type="text/javascript">\</script>
.
.
.
// Setting Datepicker properties. 
// ( I want today's date to be the max date a user can pick: )

$(function () {
   $('#addDate').datepicker({ maxDate: 0 });
});
.
.
.
```

#### Rendered HTML:

```
<input data-datepicker="True" id="addDate" name="Date" type="text" value="" />
```

Right now no additional properties I add to $('#addDate').datepicker , such as MaxDate or defaultDate seem to be taking effect. Help!

Comment: The selector (`#addDate`) doesn't match the id `addPriorityDate`. Is that the problem, or just an oversight in the example code?

Comment: Also, it would be more forward compatible (me thinks) to ditch the custom data attribute and just set the input type to `date`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that but it's actually correct in my code. I failed typing when was providing examples.

Comment: What did you mean by "sent in the header"? Just that it is in the `<head>` element before any other scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd one but I solved it. It did it when instead of using options I overwrote it with a function:

```
$('#addDate').datepicker("option", "maxDate", '+0D');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change $('#addDate').datepicker({ maxDate: 0 });  to

$('#addPriorityDate').datepicker({ maxDate: 0 });

Comment: The spec says it can take a number (assumed to be days), string (like your example, or date (I assume date object or string in date format). So it shouldn't be the value type.